# How can I scale RabbitMQ to some consumers

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to send a message to 2 **or more** consumers.
Looking at [the simple tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html) I can achieve this very easily.

But I also want to scale some of my consumers and allow **some** consumers to always process the message and **some** consumers to only process the message if it has not been processed already by another 'similar' consumer.

```
    |-------> cA
    |
P --|-------> cB'
    |   
    |-------> cB"
```

In my example above:

- `cA` will **always** process the message, regardless.
- `cB'` will **only** process the message if `cB"` has not processed the message already.
- And `cB"` will **only** process the message if `cB'` has not processed the message already.

The idea is to process data as fast as possible and, (looking at the picture above), if `cB'` or `cB"` need to contact the DB or an API, I want another consumer to pickup the data off the queue as fast as possible.
But I also do not want that data to be picked up more than once.

I could always add another publisher and have the messages removed off the queue, but I am not sure if this is really the most efficient way to achieve what I am after.

```
    |-------> cA
    |
P --|-------> p'--|-------> cB'
                  |
                  |-------> cB"
```

Is this something that could be achieved in RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly a setup with 2 queues will solve your problem.

Both queues have to be bound to the exchange(X) with the same routing key.

If you subscribe the queues in the following pattern:

- cA as the sole subscriber of queue1
- cB' and cB" sharing queue2

Routing and Subscription Overview:

```
         |--<routing key>---queue1-----cA
 P---X---|                          
         |                          |--cB'
         |--<routing key>---queue2--|
                                    |--cB"
```

The message will:

- always be process by cA and
- in a round robin manner either by cB' OR cB" (in default queue configuration). You can configure the behavior how the load is shared between cB' and cB". See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Consumer Priorities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html)
And Also [Dead Letter Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)